# Data sent by ajax call unavailable for firefox but works in chrome and Edge

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, firefox

I am making a call to my custom wordpress ajax call handler. The problem is with the data variable. The data variable shows data on chrome console but for firefox it shows "unavailable".

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
              var access_token = GetURLParameter('access_token');
              if(access_token!=null && access_token!="")
              {    //console.log(access_token);
                 var data = {
                'action': 'wp_custom_instagram_function1',
                'token': access_token
            };
            console.log(data);
            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

                window.location = '<?php echo $url ?>';
                });
             }
          });
```

Comment: Maybe is a FF bug, I would try to define the variable 'data' outside the if block: var data;if(...){data=...};

Comment: i tried that, still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing GetURLParameter with more universal function. For example

```
jQuery.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}
```

Then use it inside your code

```
var access_token = jQuery.urlParam('access_token');
```